# move_base action server doesn't come up with a real robot

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I try to run the move_base node on a real robot. When I run it in simulation (with another robot), it works successfully.
But, when I try to bring up the navigation stack on a real robot, the move_base action server doesn't come up.
Indeed, when I launch the move_base node, I get continuously the unexpected following warning:

```
[ WARN] [1466504490.216963462]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1466504490.2169, global_pose stamp: 1466504032.8989, tolerance: 0.3000
```

Moreover, when I run my own C++ node in order to send a goal command, the program stays blocked inside the waitForServer loop, this loop is as follows:

```
while(!ac.waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0)))
{
    ROS_INFO("Waiting for the move_base action server to come up");
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work and why when I run the move_base node the move_base action server doesn't come up.
If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful,
lfr

**update 1**

Here the result of the roswtf command:

```
WARNING: Package "ompl" does not follow the version conventions. It should not contain leading zeros (unless the number is 0).
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 3 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /teleop:
   * /torso_controller/state

WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:
 * /mugiro_node->/rqt_gui_py_node_4590 (/tf)

WARNING Received out-of-date/future transforms:
 * receiving transform from [/sickS3000_publisher] that differed from ROS time by -460.430734051s
 * receiving transform from [/Publish_odom_TF] that differed from ROS time by -460.43225327s
```

You can find the tf tree below:
[image: image description]

And the graph here:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237631/move_base-action-server-doesn%27t-come-up-with-a-real-robot/) by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-06-21**:
Look to your tf (`rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree` ) and node graph (`rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph`). Which topics/nodes are unconnected? What's the differences between simulation's graph and real robot's graph? Also you can use `roswtf` command for looking whats going on.

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-22**:
I updated the question, thanks for your help

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-06-22**:
I think there is a problem with your pose estimation node, In a simulation, gazebo publishes odometry and transformation between `odom` and `base_link`. I think your problem is in your `Publissh_odom_TF` node (or `mugiro_node`).

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-23**:
Ok, could you tell me what kind of problem may appear with these nodes because I still don't understand why it doesn't work.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-06-23**:
It may be **message type** *(stamped or not stamped)* or publishing with **wrong frame**. Your screenshots are from real robot. Compare them with simulation's graph and tf tree. I think you should publish odom transformation from `/mugiro_node` directly. Why you using `/Publish_odom_TF`?

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-23**:
Ah ok, thanks. But didn't write these nodes, I got the robot and these nodes from other ones. My task is to bring up the navigation stack in order to do some tests with the planner (that I have chosen). I will see about tf, I think this is the problem too. Thank you for your help.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-06-23**:
You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was the clocks of my computer and the robot was not synchronized. The difference was about 500 sec (this is why even setting the transform_tolerance value to 10 sec -> the max value, it didn't change anything). After synchronizing it, it worked properly.

Thanks to Orhangazi44 for helping me,
lfr

---

Originally posted by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) with karma: 201 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RRK](https://answers.ros.org/users/95855/rrk/) on 2022-02-01**:
Can you elaborate more, how to solve this issue?